# Can't increase partition size due to start

Tags: debian, partition, fdisk

I saw today that my computer didn't want to boot because my `/dev/sdb2` (**`/`** partition) was totally full. That was a big mistake from me, I'm a beginner and I've set the size at 10G, which isn't enough.

I started from the Debian 8 (which is my OS) install CD, and now I'm on an install shell. And Something is going wrong.

I want to increase my `/dev/sdb2` size, here's the output of `fdisk -l`:

```
Device     Start     End         Sectors     Size    Type
/dev/sdb1  2048      1050623     1048576     512M    EFI System
/dev/sdb2  1050624   20582399    19531776    9.3G    Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3  20582400  53938175    33355776    15.9G   Linux swap
/dev/sdb4  53938176  1836517375  1899586959  905.8G  Linux filesystem
```

so `/dev/sdb2` is mounted on **`/`**, and `/dev/sdb4` on `/home`. I tried decrease `/dev/sdb4`'s size, and increase `/dev/sdb2`'s but this changed the start and caused a catastrophic error. Mistakes made me learn !

Now my problem is: how can I do to increase `/dev/sdb2`'s size without changing his start (and lose everything) and without changing any other start too?

Thank you !

Comment: You could boot with one of the live cds or rescue disks and then mount your filesystems and delete unnecessary files to free up some space. After that you need to research filesystem space management, LVM will offer some flexibility. Make backups, and learn to restore from backups before you have to!

Comment: I'm puzzled that /dev/sdb2 is full with 9.3G space given that you don't have /home on it? A linux system would not normally need so much space, unless you have a huge number of programs loaded. Maybe before you put /home on /dev/sdb4 you had a /home directory on /dev/sdb2 and this is still there taking up lots of space but hidden (because /dev/sdb4 is mounted over it). So from a live CD you can `mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt` and then `du -h --summarize /mnt/home` to see how much space is used there.

Answer (score 0):

You will only get generic advice.  Here is some:

- given that /dev/sdb2 is your "/" (root) filesystem and it probably is not managed with LVM, you will have trouble resizing it.
- I would just reinstall the system - and do manual partitioning
- you probably do not need 16Gb of swap.  Perhaps the installer auto-sized it based on the amount of memory which you have.  However, swapping to disk is *much* slower than running from memory.
- but agreeing that 900Gb for /home also is excessive,  I'd use 15-20GB for the Debian 8 system, and (unless I had some application that *insisted* on having swap), give just a few GB for swap.

If you have just installed, repartitioning to get a more effective use of sdb2 vs sdb3 would be the way to go.

However - if your rescue shell has `resize2fs` and `parted`, you *could*

- shrink the filesystem on `sdb4` with `resize2fs`,
- shrink the partition, e.g., with `parted` (some people say that you can re-create a partition with `fdisk`).
- shift `sdb4` up with `parted` (to put the unused space at the beginning),
- shift up `sdb3`  with `parted` and finally
- extend `sdb2` partition (getting the space freed from `sdb4`)
- extend `sdb2` filesystem using `resize2fs`

For reference:

- [Debian system rescue](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemRescue) (needs content...)
- [How To Resize ext3 Partitions Without Losing Data](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_resizing_ext3_partitions)
- [How to Shrink an ext2/3/4 File system with resize2fs](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1196333)
- [resize2fs(8)](http://manpages.sgvulcan.com/resize2fs.8.php)
- [parted(8)](http://manpages.sgvulcan.com/parted.8.php)